# Difference between <type*[n]> and <type(*)[n]> in C++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I wanted to create a queue to store two dimensional arrays of chars and I thought that declaring it in the following way would work:

```
queue<char*[7]> states;
```

However, it turned out that the right way was:

```
queue<char(*)[7]> states;
```

And I can't really understand what do the round brackets change? I guess it has something to do with precedence, but nothing more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char*[7]` is an array of seven pointers to `char`, `char(*)[7]` is a pointer to an array of seven `char`s. Often it's used to allocate dynamically contiguous multidimensional arrays (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837664/214671)).

The [C++ FAQ about arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810676#4810676) may give you some insight about these subtleties.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to remember the meaning of `char*[7]` is that that's the form of the second argument to `main`.

I.e. it means an array of pointers.

Then `char(*)[7]` is easiest to analyze by introducing a name, like `char(*p)[7]`. Since C declarations were designed to mimic use of the declared things, this means that you can dereference `p`, and index the result, then yielding a `char`. I.e. `p` is a pointer to an array of `char`.

Comment: "An easy way to remember the meaning of char*[7] is that that's the form of the second argument to main." I find the example of `main` confusing since you can write it without the `[]` operator: `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: @nouney: Yes, as a formal function argument an array type (and also a function type) decays to pointer type. The second arg of `main` thing is a mnemonic, a device to remember things. Due to the decay it *is* a pointer, to the first item of the array, but the whole reason for the decay is that we can and usually do think of it as directly being the array, which is how it aids memory here. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`char*[7]` is an array of pointer to `char`.
`char(*)[7]` is a pointer referencing an array of `char`.